# How to compare values for last and second last entry in table?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I have a table in Oracle called quotes with two columns: *date* and *value*.

I would like to compare values for last entry and second last entry in the table.

In this example I would like to get dates for **13.1 and 11.1**  in one line and the difference between the values for each date (10-5=5).

---

**Quotes Table:**

Date    -    Value

13.1.2010    -    10

11.1.2010    -     5

10.1.2010    -     2

8.10.2010    -     1

---

### Edit:

I would like to have more complex table with one more column *companyId*. I need to get items for each company. Table would look like this:

**Quotes Table:**

Date    -    Value       -  CompanyId

**13.1.2010    -    10     -  10**

11.1.2010    -     5     -  10

10.1.2010    -     2     -  10

8.10.2010    -     1     -  10

**12.1.2010    -     7     -  20**

10.1.2010    -     3     -  20

9.1.2010    -     2     -  20

8.10.2010    -     2     -  20

I would like to get two lines in this case (*but in general just get as many lines as the number of companies are*) - one for each company that will return both dates and difference between newest value and second newest value.
So in this case it would return:

companyId 10 13.1 and 11.1 and 5 and another line like this:

companyId 20 12.1 and 10.1 and 4 ( 7-3=4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *, value - nextvalue AS diff
FROM    (
        SELECT  m.*, LEAD(value) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) AS nextvalue
        FROM    mytable m
        ORDER BY
                date DESC
        )
WHERE   rownum = 1
```

**Update:**

To select results company-wise:

```
SELECT  value - nextvalue AS diff
FROM    (
        SELECT  m.*,
                LEAD(value) OVER (PARTITION BY companyId ORDER BY date DESC) AS nextvalue,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY companyId ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
        FROM    mytable m
        )
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: I have updated the question with more complex table. Have you any idea how to solve it?