# Compare last to second last record for each contract

Tags: sql, ms-access

To keep it simple, my question is similar to [THIS QUESTION, PART 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072029/how-to-compare-values-for-last-and-second-last-entry-in-table), only problem is, I am not running Oracle and thus can not use the rownumbers.

For those who need more information and examples:

I have a table

```
  contractId date          value    
  1          09/02/2011     A         
  1          13/02/2011     C          
  2          02/02/2011     D   
  2          08/02/2011     A  
  2          12/02/2011     C  
  3          22/01/2011     C  
  3          30/01/2011     B  
  3          12/02/2011     D    
  3          21/01/2011     A
```

**EDIT:** added another line for ContractID. Since I had some code myself, but that would display the following:

```
  contractId date          value    value_old
  1          09/02/2011     A                  
  2          08/02/2011     A         D
  3          30/01/2011     B         C    
  3          30/01/2011     B         A
```

But that is **not** what I want ! The result should still be as below!

Now I want to select the last record before a given date and compare that with the previous value.
**Suppose the 'given date' is 11/02/2011 in this example**, the output should be like this:

```
  contractId date          value    value_old
  1          09/02/2011     A                  
  2          08/02/2011     A         D
  3          30/01/2011     B         C
```

I do have the query to select the last record before the given date. That is the easy part. But to select the last record *before* that, I am lost...

I really hope I can get some help here, have been breaking my head over this for days and looking for answers on the web and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
SELECT a.contractId, a.Date, a.Value, (SELECT Top 1 b.[Value] 
        FROM tbl b 
        WHERE b.[Date] < a.[Date] And b.ContractID=a.ContractID
        ORDER BY b.[Date] Desc) AS Old_Value
FROM tbl AS a
WHERE a.Date IN 
       (SELECT TOP 1 b.Date 
        FROM tbl b 
        WHERE b.ContractID=a.ContractID
        AND b.Date < #2011/02/11#
        ORDER BY b.date DESC)
```

Comment: @Remou This method does not work, it will only give one row of data since you use the 'Top 1' method. I think the previous answer, that is deleted now, was more on the right track although using a lot of joins. I now have it covered with 3 seperate queries, first one taking the last rows, 2nd one the second to last rows and 3rd one combining the two. Probably not efficient at all, but best I can get right now. Will post detailed answer later. Really wondering how people compare data in their history table then....

Comment: @Yohsoog I have altered the query. It is not quite clear to me why there is no old value for contract ID 1, so the above query includes an old value for that ID.

Comment: @Remou I will test your update later, but the reason there is no old value for ID 1 is that you missed my 'filter' described in the middle of the text about the 'given date' being 11/02/2011. Therefore, the latest value of ID 1 at that given date is A and there is no value known for A before that.

Comment: Not quite, but re-reading the data I get your point. I have posted another example.

Comment: @Remou This works!! Yes, I am amazed :) I started working from your previous ideas, but could not get further then the previous ideas I told you about here. I will post them too, but you answer at least looks a lot more efficient (will test it later whith my real data). Also added another line in the example to create possibility of having more then one date lower then the max below 11/02/2011 (and your code still stands ;) ). Thanks again. (PS: can only accept, not vote up, not enough rep yet)

Answer (score 0):

As promised, I would also post my answer. Although at this point, I still think Remou's answer is better, since the code is shorter and it seems more efficient (calls the same table fewer times). But here goes:

Query1:

```
SELECT c.contractID, c.firstofdates, a.value, d.value, d.date
FROM (table1 AS A RIGHT JOIN (SELECT b.cid,max(b.date) AS FirstOfdates
FROM table1 as B
where b.date < #02/11/2011#
GROUP BY b.contractID    )  AS c ON (a.date = c.firstofdates) AND (a.contractID =   c.contractID)) 
LEFT JOIN (select e.contractID, e.date, e.value
from table1 as e
)  AS d ON (d.date < c.firstofdates) AND (d.contractID = c.contractID);
```

This query actually gives the result with the extra row for the 3rd contractID.

Query2:

```
SELECT b.contractID, max(a.date) AS olddate
FROM table1 AS a RIGHT JOIN (select contractID, firstofdates 
from Query1)  AS b ON (a.contractID= b.contractID) AND (a.date < b.firstofdates)
GROUP BY b.contractID;
```

And then to combine both:

Query3:

```
SELECT Query1.contractID, Query1.firstofdates AS [date], Query1.A.value AS [value], Query1.d.value  AS [old value]
FROM Query1 RIGHT JOIN Query2 
ON (Query1.date=Query2.olddate or Query2.olddate is null) AND   (Query1.cid = Query2.cid);
```